# Is `a<b<c` valid python?

Tags: python

I was curious to see if I could use this `a<b<c` as a conditional without using the standard `a<b and b<c`. So I tried it out and my test results passed.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

assert(a<b<c) # In bounds test
assert(not(b<a<c)) # Out of bounds test
assert(not(a<c<b)) # Out of bounds test
```

Just for good measure I tried more numbers, this time in the negative region. Where `a, b, c = -10, -9, -8`. The test passed once again. Even the test suit at a higher range works `a, b, c = 10, 11, 12`. Or even `a, b, c = 10, 20, 5`.

And the same experiment done in C++. This was my mentality going into it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=10;
    b=20;
    c=5;
    cout << ((a<b<c)?"True":"False") << endl; // Provides True (wrong)
    cout << ((a<b && b<c)?"True":"False") << endl; // Provides False (proper answer)
    return 0;
}
```

I originally though that this implementation would be invalid since in every other language I have come across would evaluate a boolean before it would reach `c`. With those languages, `a<b` would evaluate to a boolean and continuing the evaluation, `b<c`, would be invalid since it would attempt to evaluate a boolean against a number (most likely throwing a compile time error or falsifying the intended comparison). This is a little unsettling to me for some reason. I guess I just need to be reassured that this is part of the syntax. It would also be helpful to provide a reference to where this feature is provided in the Python documentation so I can see to what extent they provide features like this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN
>   are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent
>   to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

And, as an example,

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Answer (score 1):

Python chains relational operators "naturally". Note that Python's relational operators include `in` and `is` (and their negatives), which can lead to some surprising results when mixing them with the symbolic relational operators.